# vuejs register component issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, apexcharts

I installed [ApexChart](https://github.com/apexcharts/vue-apexcharts) via

```
npm install vue-apexcharts
```

on and on my `bootstrap.js` file i import it as

```
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts'
Vue.use(VueApexCharts)
```

and on my `app.js file` i import the bootstrap.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');
Vue.component('products', require('./components/ProductComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('employees', require('./components/EmployeesComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('orders', require('./components/OrdersComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('display-products', require('./components/DisplayProducts.vue'));
Vue.component('order-products', require('./components/OrderProductComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('dashboard', require('./components/DashboardComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

on my vue file i tried

```
<apexcharts width="500" type="bar" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apexcharts>
```

but im getting `did you register the component correctly?`

Im using laravel w/ vue js

EDIT I've done a fiddle : It is still not working

https://jsfiddle.net/nicolas1000/rke9xadq/

Answer (score 3):

You need to register the component like this if you want to use:

`components: {
   apexcharts: VueApexCharts
}`

The complete example is here:

```
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts'

export default {
    components: {
      apexcharts: VueApexCharts,
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        chartOptions: {
          chart: {
            id: 'vuechart-example'
          },
          xaxis: {
            categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'series-1',
          data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91]
        }]
      }
    },
};
```

Comment: im getting VueApexCharts is not defined

Comment: You mentioned in the original question you are getting this error *but im getting did you register the component correctly?*

Comment: I dont think VueApexCharts support plugins, so you have to do it like this answer. You still need to import it though.

Answer (score 1):

```
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts'
Vue.use(VueApexCharts)

Vue.component('apexchart', VueApexCharts)
```

Inside your main file(bootstrap.js) you need to import it in this way and then use  in every of your file.